# SQL - Create all possible combinations

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have few classes and I want to **create all possible combinations.**

### Class table

```
ColA
A
B
C
D
E
```

Output (not that if I have A,B as output I don't want B,A as well, etc.)

```
ColA    Col2 
A        B
A        C
A        D
A        E
B        C
B        D
B        E
C        D
C        E
D        E
```

I don't want to use cursors.

Comment: want to create all possible combinations of class provided above.

Comment: `select t1.colA as cola, t2.colA as Col2 from the_table t1 cross join the_table t2;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( ID CHAR(1) )

INSERT  INTO @t VALUES  ( 'A' )
INSERT  INTO @t VALUES  ( 'B' )
INSERT  INTO @t VALUES  ( 'C' )
INSERT  INTO @t VALUES  ( 'D' )
INSERT  INTO @t VALUES  ( 'E' )

;WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   ID ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY (SELECT 1) ) AS rn
               FROM     @t
             )
    SELECT  t1.ID ,
            t2.ID
    FROM    cte t1
            JOIN cte t2 ON t2.rn > t1.rn
    ORDER BY t1.ID ,
            t2.ID
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do this by adding a condition:

```
select c1.cola as col1, c2.cola as col2
from class c1 join
     class c2
     on c1.cola < c2.cola;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE #a (a CHAR(1));
INSERT INTO #a VALUES ('A');
INSERT INTO #a VALUES ('B');
INSERT INTO #a VALUES ('C');
INSERT INTO #a VALUES ('D');
INSERT INTO #a VALUES ('E');

SELECT a.a, b.a FROM #a a CROSS JOIN #a b
--If you do not need the same combinations such as AA then do like that
SELECT a.a, b.a FROM #a a CROSS JOIN #a b  WHERE a.a <> b.a
```

Comment: I want only one row like from these two {A B, B A}.. same as commutative rule AB=BA

Comment: This answer definitely does not deserve a downvote.